# TransactionRequiredException when merging an entity

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

In the application I am building I load data from the database, display it in a `p:dataGrid` where The user can edit some values. After editing the user will click on a "Save" button which will store the edited values in the database.

I wrote a solution that worked just fine, but after a few republishes and/or server restarts I started to get `TransactionRequiredException`s at `myEntityFacade.edit(item)` in the `saveAction()` method.

In `View.xhtml`:

```
<p:dataGrid id="itemGrid" var="item"
    value="#{myController.itemList}" columns="6"
    layout="grid" style="width:100%">
    <p:panel style="text-align:center;width:100%">
        <!-- Displaying data -->
    </p:panel>
</p:dataGrid>

<p:commandButton value="Save" id="saveBtn"
    action="#{myController.saveAction}"
    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
```

In `MyController.java`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myController")
@SessionScoped
public class MyController {

    @Inject
    private MyEntityFacade myEntityFacade;
    private List<MyEntity> itemList;

    ... Constructor and other member declarations

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        itemList = myEntityFacade.findAll();
    }

    public void saveAction() {
        for(MyEntity item : itemList) {
            myEntityFacade.edit(item);
        }
    }

    ... Getters and Setters

}
```

In `MyEntityFacade.java`:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEntityFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<MyEntity> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(MyEntity.class));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public void edit(MyEntity entity) {
        em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Am I using PrimeFaces and/or JPA as they are supposed to be used? What could be the cause of the `TransactionRequiredException`?

**Additional information:**

- PrimeFaces 5.3
- JPA 2.0
- Glassfish 4.1 (being run from NetBeans 8.2)
- The .war file is built using Maven

Comment: and where is your transaction?

Comment: Paste code where you saving edited entities.

Comment: @Neil transaction is started by container, when entering Stateles EJB method.

Comment: evidently not, otherwise the message would not be there. Any exception has a stack trace and that tells the user where the message comes from ... JPA provider?

Comment: @PeterSaly Sorry. The facade has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable JTA in perisistence.xml `<persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">` and in application server datasource too if it has such setting.

Comment: Check if glassfish is creating JTA transaction in EJB